# Why is the output different even though the expressions are the same in lambda expression?

Tags: c++, lambda

I have problem about lambda expression like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std; 

int sum(vector<int>& v){
    int total = 0;
    auto lambda = for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [&total](int n){total += n;});
    lambda; // lambda expression doesn't work.
    for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [&total](int n){total += n;}); // work same as I intended.
    return total;
}

int main(void){
    vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    cout << sum(v) << endl; // 30 (I think this should be 45.)
}
```

I thought that `lambda;` could do same things like `for_each` algorithm. Why `lambda;` doesn't works?

Comment: `lamda;` doesn't *call* the lambda function. And according to [the `std::for_each` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) it returns the function you pass, not an object that does the `std::for_each`.

Comment: You should probably also read about the [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) function.

Comment: Your `lambda` is not a lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each), the `for_each(...)` call returns the `UnaryFunction` which was passed to the function.

In this case, the `for_each` returns the UnaryFunction

```
[&total](int n){total += n;}
```

a `lambda(5)` would increase the `total` value by 5.

A solution would be to put the `for_each` call in a separate function - which is actually a "sum" function.
This is already done by the `std:accumulate` function

```
std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If do not take into account the side effect of accumulating the variable total this declaration

```
auto lambda = for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [&total](int n){total += n;});
```

in fact is equivalent to

```
auto lambda = [&total](int n){total += n;};
```

So this statement

```
lambda; // lambda expression doesn't work.
```

does not make a sense.

So the declaration of the lambda expression is just redundant.

In fact you called the algorithm std::for_each two times in this declaration

```
auto lambda = for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [&total](int n){total += n;});
```

and in this statement

```
for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [&total](int n){total += n;});
```